# Caml query not working for view creation sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, csom, caml

I am creating a Sharepoint List View using C# CSOM code. I'm using ViewCreationInformation to create my view. I'm facing problem in writing the query for it.

Writing this works:

```
            ViewCollection viewColl = list.Views;
            string[] viewFields = {"Id", "Action", "Created", "Created By"};
            ViewCreationInformation creationInfo = new ViewCreationInformation();
            creationInfo.Title = "FromCode";
            creationInfo.ViewFields = viewFields;
            creationInfo.Query = @"<Where><Neq><FieldRef Name=""ConfidentialDocument""/><Value Type=""Choice"">No</Value></Neq></Where><GroupBy><FieldRef Name=""TemplateName"" /><FieldRef Name=""Title"" /></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=""Created"" Ascending=""True"" /></OrderBy>";
            creationInfo.ViewTypeKind = ViewType.Html;
            creationInfo.RowLimit = 30;
            creationInfo.Paged = true;
            creationInfo.SetAsDefaultView = true;
            viewColl.Add(creationInfo);
```

But If I change the query to this:

```
            creationInfo.Query = @"<Where><Neq><FieldRef Name=""ConfidentialDocument""/><Value Type=""Choice"">No</Value></Neq></Where><GroupBy Collapse=""TRUE"" GroupLimit=""30""><FieldRef Name=""TemplateName"" /><FieldRef Name=""Title"" /></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=""Created"" Ascending=""True"" /></OrderBy>";
```

Then the View displays an error:
[TypeError: Unable to get property 'substring' of undefined or null reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u5vK.png)

You can check the link or here is the error: 
TypeError: Unable to get property 'substring' of undefined or null reference

```
  TypeError: Unable to get property 'substring' of undefined or null referenceTypeError: Unable to get property '_events' of undefined or null reference
```

Does anyone have any idea about this? I've searched many places and I found similar codes everywhere. I don't know why this code is not working.

Comment: I should tell you that I don't have access to Microsoft.SharePoint.dll.
I am using Microsoft.Sharepoint.client.dll (all the client dll's to be precise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem was with GroupLimit=""30"". Query without GroupLimit works totally fine.

```
        creationInfo.Query = @"<Where><Neq><FieldRef Name=""ConfidentialDocument""/><Value Type=""Choice"">No</Value></Neq></Where><GroupBy Collapse=""TRUE""><FieldRef Name=""TemplateName"" /><FieldRef Name=""Title"" /></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=""Created"" Ascending=""True"" /></OrderBy>";
```